# Showing a homotopy is continuous, explicitly.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I am trying to show that the map $H:S^1\times I\rightarrow S^1$ given by $H(z,t)=e^{it\theta}z$ is continuous, where $\theta$ is a fixed angle.

If I take an open set $U\in S^1$, then I want to show that $H^{-1}(U)$ is open in $S^1\times I$. Thus, I want to show that $H^{-1}(U)$ is a union of sets of the form $J\times K$ where $J$ is open in $S^1$ and $K$ is open in $I$.

Now, $H^{-1}(U)=\{(z,t)\in S^1\times I\mid e^{it\theta}z\in U\}$. Let $(x',t')\in H^{-1}(U)$. Then $H(x',t')\in U$ and so there exists a neighborhood $V$ of $H(x',t')$ such that $V\subseteq U$.

Is it enough to say that $(x',t')\in H^{-1}(V)\subseteq H^{-1}(U)$ and so the map is open? If not what am I missing. Is there a more obvious way to show that this map is open?

Comment: I suppose $\theta$ is supposed to be some fixed angle?

Comment: Yes, I fixed it.

Comment: Is this not just the composition of $S^1\times I\rightarrow S^1\times I$, $(z,t)\mapsto(z,t\cdot \theta)$ with $1\times exp:S^1\times I\rightarrow S^1\times S^1$ and the multiplication on $S^1$?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Are you trying to show that this map is open or that it is continuous? If you are trying to show that it is continuous, is it a problem to say that it is a product and composition of continuous maps?

Comment: It might be worth noting that more generally, if $f:A\to A'$ and $g:B\to B'$ are continuous and $p:A'\times B'\to C'$ is continuous, then $h:A\times B\to C$ defined as $h(a,b)=p(f(a),g(b))$ is continuous. In the above case, $A=S^1, B=I, A'=S^1, B'=S^1, and C=S^1.$ $p(w,z)=w\cdot z$ in $S^1$, $f(a)=a,g(b)=e^{i\theta b}.$

Comment: In this case, it is far easier to express your function as a composition of continuous functions (as the comments and answer suggests) than it is to use the definition. There are common “building block” functions that are useful e.g. multiplication, addition, exponentiation, projection, inclusion, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think your argument only works if you know that $H^{-1}(V)$ is open... but that is what you are trying to prove in the first place.

However this is one of those functions where you would say that it is "obviously" continuous. Why? Well obviously $G:\mathbb{C}^2 \to \mathbb{C}, (z, t) \mapsto e^{i \theta t} z$ is continuous, and you function is just the restriction of $G$ to the subset $S^1 \times I \subset \mathbb{C}^2$, hence continuous. (Actually the crucial part is that $S^1 \times I$ is also a **topological subspace**, i.e. it has subset topology with respect to $\mathbb{C}^2$)

Comment: Why is $G$ continuous?

Comment: multiplication is continuous and the exponential function is continuous